# Should I take a student loan now, if I intend to become a mathematician?

Tags: funding, undergraduate, france

I intend to pursue my degree in Mathematics and Physics at Ecole Polytechnique in France. The institution has offered me an interest free loan of 18,000 euros, which has to be repaid three years after I complete my bachelor's degree.

Since I am passionate about basic sciences, I hope to join a five year PhD programme after my degree and this usually comes with a decent scholarship/stipend. Approximate salary for PhD scholars in Europe is about 1300 euros, though this might vary from institution. Right now, I am not sure whether this salary and the one received during Post-Doc might be enough for me to repay these loans and therefore, I wish seek advice on this matter from the Academia Stack Exchange community which, I believe, will be in a better position to answer  this question since most members are pursuing a career in Academia.

Comment: If you graduate at École Polytechnique, you will be coming out with a Masters on top of the Bachelors degree. Are you sure that the date is 3 years after you obtain the BSc instead of 3 years after your graduation? By the way, check out the Paris Saclay and Jacques Hadamard Foundations scholarships for international students.

Comment: I'm not sure how postdoc salaries fit in here, since it sounds like the loan will be due before you finish your PhD.  Whether you can repay it out of your PhD salary would of course depend on how much money you spend on everything else (which in turn depends on the cost of living where you study, etc).  So it's hard to answer for sure but in any case it sounds like it would be very difficult.  Is there any possibility of refinancing the loan after three years?

Comment: Have you checked with the Ecole Polytechnique if repayment for this loan would be deferred for people in graduate studies?

Comment: I would probably focus on completing your undergrad first. It's great that you have a life plan, but it may be that you change your mind about wanting to pursue a research degree/academic career afterwards.

Comment: Just one question: do you need it?

Comment: @MarkoKarbevski Ecole Polytechnique has recently started a Bachelor's program, which is different from the Ingenieur Diploma program and thus I will not lead to a Master's degree after graduation. Details about the program can be found at this link (https://portail.polytechnique.edu/bachelor/en).

Comment: @NateEldredge I am not aware of any possibility of refinancing the loan, since all the documents pertaining to the loan have not been sent to me. The program coordinator has only outlined the basic information. Beginning from my first year as an undergrad till the end of the 6th year, I do not have to pay anything. Repayment starts from 7th year and must end in the 10th year. I would thus have to 4500 euros per year.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Ecole Polytechnique expects that after my 3 year bachelor program, I will study for an additional three years. Therefore, the loan repayment starts in the 7th year.

Comment: @MikeMiller Certainly that could be the case. But I have to make a decision now and I don't want to regret this choice later on.

Comment: @Greg It will be hard for my family to afford the education otherwise, but if we stretch our finances then I probably won't need the loan.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more about personal finances than academia.  It *might* be on topic at Money.SE

Comment: @Supermario: Ah, I misunderstood - I thought you meant you had to *finish* repaying the loan by three years after your bachelor's.  If this gets reopened, or reposted somewhere else, please clarify that in the question.  Also, by "refinance" I meant taking out a new loan to pay off the original one - so it wouldn't be described in the loan documents, it's more about what other loans might be available in your country.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος How do I remove it, I mean the question?

Comment: @Supermario 1) closed questions aren't necessarily delete-worthy 2) you have already got an answer to this question, and the answer is high-quality and not yours 3) when you joined this site, you agreed to terms that specify that, after you post any content, "You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so." (section 3 in [legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal))

Answer (score 1):

Before answering whether you should take the loan you need to ask yourself some basic questions.

1. Would I go to the school if there was no loan available?
2. How would I pay for the school without the loan?
3. Are you good at budgeting your money?

If you would not go to the school without the loan, the answer to the big question depends on why the loan influence's your decision. The answer is almost always that debt is bad. If you would go to the school without the loan, have a means of paying for school and are good at budgeting, then take the loan and put it in a secure investment. At the end of the 3 years, cash out the investment, pay off the loan and pocket the interest. If you are bad at budgeting, you want to be careful about taking on debt and the answer is almost always debt is bad.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't think that it would be possible for me to attend this program without the loan unless my parents really stretch their pockets. The fact that the loan is interest free is what makes it a bit compelling for me to consider attending this college. Plus it has a great math program too.